# problemas al editar una fila

Tags: android-studio

Hola amigos del foro esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, estoy realizando una pequeña aplicación en la cual poseo una tabla (tablelayout), la cual funciona bien al momento de ingresar y grabar, también el buscar un registro, pero ahora lo que deseo es seleccionar una fila y editarla a las distintas edittext que poseo, este es el código que poseo actualmente.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et_busqueda, et_filas, et_tipo, et_marca, et_modelo, colFilas, colTipo, colMarca, colModelo, et_activo;
Button cmdingresar, modificar;
TableLayout tbldatos;
private String[]header={"N° Filas","Tipo","Marca","Modelo"};
private ArrayList<String[]> rows=new ArrayList<>();
private TableRow tableRow;
private TableDynamic tableDynamic;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et_busqueda = findViewById(R.id.txtbusqueda5);
    et_filas = findViewById(R.id.txtitem);
    et_filas.setEnabled(false);
    et_tipo = findViewById(R.id.txttipo);
    et_marca = findViewById(R.id.txtmarca);
    et_modelo = findViewById(R.id.txtmodelo);
    et_activo = findViewById(R.id.txtactivo5);
    cmdingresar = findViewById(R.id.cmdingresar);
    modificar = findViewById(R.id.cmdmodificar);
    tbldatos = findViewById(R.id.tbldatos);

    tableDynamic = new TableDynamic(tbldatos, getApplicationContext());
    tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
    tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
    tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
    tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
    tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
    tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
    tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
    et_tipo.requestFocus();
    mostrardatos();
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    cmdingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.1.96/oficina/insertar_vehiculos.php");
        }
    });
}

private ArrayList<String[]> getClients(){

    return rows;
}

private void ejecutarServicio (String URL) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos grabados satisfactoriamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            datos();
            insertar();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vuelva a intentarlo, este registro ya existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            int b = 1;
            int val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(et_filas.getText()));
            int val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(b));
            int suma = val1 + val2;
            String valorTotal = Integer.toString(suma);
            et_filas.setText(valorTotal);
        }
    }) {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String a = "1";
            et_activo.setText(a);
            parametros.put("Tipo_Vehiculo",et_tipo.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Marca_Vehiculo",et_marca.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Modelo_Vehiculo",et_modelo.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Activo",et_activo.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void datos (){
    String[]item = new String[]{et_filas.getText().toString(),et_tipo.getText().toString(),et_marca.getText().toString(),et_modelo.getText().toString()};
    tableDynamic.addItems(item);
}

public void insertar(){
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message1).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
    builder.setMessage("¿Desea seguir ingresando?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            int b = 1;
            int val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(et_filas.getText()));
            int val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(b));
            int suma = val1 + val2;
            String valorTotal = Integer.toString(suma);
            et_filas.setText(valorTotal);
            et_tipo.setText("");
            et_marca.setText("");
            et_modelo.setText("");
            et_tipo.requestFocus();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            et_tipo.setText("");
            et_marca.setText("");
            et_modelo.setText("");
            et_tipo.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("Oficina");
    alert.show();
}

public void mostrardatos (){
    String url = "http://192.168.1.96/oficina/buscar_vehiculos.php";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    LayoutInflater reg1 = getLayoutInflater();
                    View registro = reg1.inflate(R.layout.tabla,null, false);
                    colFilas=registro.findViewById(R.id.colFilas);
                    colTipo=registro.findViewById(R.id.colTipo);
                    colMarca=registro.findViewById(R.id.colMarca);
                    colModelo=registro.findViewById(R.id.colModelo);
                    colFilas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                    colTipo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Tipo_Vehiculo"));
                    colMarca.setText(jsonObject.getString("Marca_Vehiculo"));
                    colModelo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Modelo_Vehiculo"));
                    tbldatos.addView(registro);
                    int j = 1;
                    for (int x = 0; x <= tbldatos.getChildCount(); x++) {
                        int suma = x + j;
                        et_filas.setText("" + suma);
                    }
                    int b = 1;
                    int val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(et_filas.getText()));
                    int val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(b));
                    int suma = val1 + val2;
                    String valorTotal = Integer.toString(suma);
                    et_filas.setText(valorTotal);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

public void Consultar (View view) {
    tbldatos.removeAllViews();
    String url = "http://192.168.1.96/oficina/buscar_vehiculos1.php?Marca_Vehiculo=" + et_busqueda.getText().toString();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    LayoutInflater reg1 = getLayoutInflater();
                    View registro = reg1.inflate(R.layout.tabla, null, false);
                    colFilas = registro.findViewById(R.id.colFilas);
                    colTipo = registro.findViewById(R.id.colTipo);
                    colMarca = registro.findViewById(R.id.colMarca);
                    colModelo = registro.findViewById(R.id.colModelo);
                    colFilas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                    colTipo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Tipo_Vehiculo"));
                    colMarca.setText(jsonObject.getString("Marca_Vehiculo"));
                    colModelo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Modelo_Vehiculo"));
                    tbldatos.addView(registro);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

public void Tablaeditar (View view){
    idFilas = view.toString();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://192.168.1.96/oficina/buscar_vehiculos2.php?N_Filas = {idFilas}";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                et_filas.setText(response.getString("N_Filas"));
                et_tipo.setText(response.getString("Tipo_Vehiculo"));
                et_marca.setText(response.getString("Marca_Vehiculo"));
                et_modelo.setText(response.getString("Modelo_Vehiculo"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

}

y este el código que utilizo en el layout resource file denominada tabla.xml

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:onClick="Tableregistro"
tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colFilas"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/item"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colTipo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/tipo1"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colMarca"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/marca"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colModelo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/modelo"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
```

en el Tablaeditar es en la función que pretendo realizar la edición de la fila y que al seleccionar se marca y así poder llevar dichos datos a las distintas cajas de texto, ojala que me puedan asesorar de como puedo hacerlo en forma correcta, ya lo que he investigado todos los ejemplos los realizan a través de SQLite, y estoy utilizando actualmente en mysql con java para android, y desde ya muchas gracias, además al ejecutarlo me manda este error  **org.json.JSONException:Value<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**.
Por otro lado se adjunta una imagen para que puedan ver que es lo que se pretende hacer, ya que esto mismo lo realice en netbeans con java, así que creo que se debe hacer.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Jorgesys ya lo revise a través de postman con cada uno de los campos y funciona muy bien el código en php, pienso que el error para mi esta en esta linea **idFilas = view.toString();**, la cual la he traspasado a entero y sigue dando el mismo error, ya no se que mas hacer, me encuentro muy decepcionado por este error, favor de asesorarme

Answer (score 0):

Definitivamente se puede lo que indicas pero tienes un problema que debes corregir:

> org.json.JSONException:Value<br of type java.lang.String cannot be
> converted to JSONObject.

La petición que realizas obtiene un valor que no es un `JSONObject` y no puede ser procesada.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, lo solucione en el php, tenias toda la razón era el de las filas que estaba dando el problema, por eso el error, lo consideraba como un string y lo traspase a int y ningún problema, funciona bien ahora